# Simulating Bayesian Power Priors

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

I'm trying to implement Bayesian power priors to discount historical data.

$$\pi^p(\theta|\mathbf{z_{n_0}},a_0)  \propto
\pi_0(\theta) * L(\theta;\mathbf{z_{n_0}})^{a_0}$$

where $\pi^p$ is the posterior, $\pi_0$ is the prior, $L$ is the likelihood function, $\theta$ are the parameters of interest, $\mathbf{z_{n_0}}$ is the historical data, and $a_0 \in [0,1]$ is the discounting factor.

My problem consists of five parameters, and if $a_0 =1$, I can simulate it using an MCMC method like Gibbs sampler. There is no conjugate prior and accompanying closed-form solution available in my problem. If $a_0 = 0$, the posterior equals the prior and no updating is required.

For any other value of $a_0$, I haven't come across any ways of getting the result. If conjugate priors are used, there are closed form solutions ([examples in Section 5](https://catalyst.harvard.edu/pdf/biostatsseminar/Santis-2007-Using%20historical%20data%20for%20Bayesian%20sample%20size.pdf)).

---

@Florian, yes I want to estimate the posterior. Sorry for the confusion.

@Björn, thanks for the suggestion. I am looking at a fixed exponent and am using R, so I will try rstan. I'll report back afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, by simulating, do you mean you want to know how you can estimate the posterior for this model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gibbs sampling will indeed not be usable unless a conjugate or conditionally conjugate prior exists. However, there are other perfectly good MCMC sampling methods. If you are using a fixed $a_0$, you can trivially do this in any software for MCMC sampling that allows you to specify a user defined log-likelihood e.g. Stan (can be used from within many statistics packages, e.g. in R using the rstan package), PROC MCMC in the SAS/STAT software and so on. E.g. in Stan you could specify this form of the power prior as

```
target += a0*logLhist(theta,zn) + logpi0(theta);
```

where you would have to define appropriate functions for the log-likelihood of the historical prior and log-pdf of the initial prior (or use some pre-defined pdfs or pmfs).

Note that if you want to use the formulation of the power prior with a non-fixed $a_0$, there is a complicated normalization of the power prior that is necessary (see ["A note on the power prior"](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/sim.3722)). For that you need to do some numeric integration in each step of the MCMC sampling, but even that is possible in all the software I mentioned above.

Comment: Using stan via R (rstan) worked.  Updating the $target$ variable as suggested is one potential solution, but I didn't go through with it and instead wrote user-defined likelihood functions that include $a_0$.  See <https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303905613_Bayesian_inference_with_Stan_A_tutorial_on_adding_custom_distributions> for more details.  Thanks!